# SQL: subquery for unary table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a subquery that groups identical TickerSymbols togather as well as TickerSentiment that is between two values e.g. 0.0001 and 1

**Sample Rows**

```
TickerID    CommentID   TickerSymbol    TickerSentiment
3           3           DTE             0
4           3           SPY             0
7           6           MATX            -0.5574
9           8           ETSY            -0.5216
12          11          ROKU            -0.0926
14          13          ROKU            -0.7351
15          14          BROKU           0
17          16          SPY             -0.1531
18          17          CHGG            0.3612
29          28          AMP             0
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT TickerSymbol,
  (
        SELECT count(p.TickerSymbol) 
        FROM Ticker p
        WHERE p.TickerSymbol IS NOT "NONE" AND p.TickerSentiment BETWEEN 0.000000001 and 1 
    ) as "Positive Sentiment"
       
FROM Ticker
WHERE TickerSymbol IS NOT "NONE"
```

**Output**

```
TickerSymbol    Positive Sentiment
DTE             3573
SPY             3573
MATX            3573
ETSY            3573
ROKU            3573
ROKU            3573
BROKU           3573
SPY             3573
```

**Desired Output**

```
TickerSymbol    Positive Sentiment
DTE             101
SPY             46
MATX            24
ETSY            91
ROKU            24
BROKU           51
```

Comment: Sample data would help your question.

Comment: sure i can add some.

Comment: he subquery mus be related to the outer SELect, but i can't figure out what you are trying to count

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sample code will not work in MySQL

But i think you are looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TickerSymbol, pos_stat as 'Positive Sentiment'       
FROM Ticker t INNER JOIN 
  (
        SELECT p.TickerSymbol , COUNT(*) as pos_stat
        FROM Ticker p
        WHERE p.TickerSymbol NOT LIKE  'NONE' AND p.TickerSentiment BETWEEN 0.000000001 and 1 
        GROUP BY p.TickerSymbol
    ) t1 ON t.TickerSymbol = t1.TickerSymbol
WHERE TickerSymbol  NOT LIKE 'NONE'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forget to specify related condition in your subquery. That's why your result would all be the same.
online sample: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/htMM5HutjHrKkGEx7TPR4j/0

```sql
SELECT Distinct TickerSymbol,
  (
        SELECT count(p.TickerSymbol) 
        FROM Ticker p
        WHERE p.TickerSentiment BETWEEN 0.000000001 and 1 
                and Ticker.TickerSymbol = p.TickerSymbol
    ) as "Positive Sentiment"
FROM Ticker
WHERE TickerSymbol != "NONE"
```

Second problem is when you compare string, you should use `!=` instead of `is not`. Like @nbk said it is not a valid sql in MySQL.
The doc mention `IS` is using for boolean or null comparison.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#expression-syntax